# Как получать значение города из строки?

Tags: php, вконтакте, callback

Пытаюсь работать с Callback VK. Хотелось бы сделать простенький прогноз, но для этого пользователю нужно указать город. Как этот город впоследствии найти в строке? Чтобы составить ссылку и получить погоду в этом городе. Есть идея найти слово с большой буквы, но не в начале строки. Как-нибудь так можно найти это слово?

Comment: простенький прогноз чего? И зачем эта инфа вообще? Просто дайте пример строки из которой надо получить город. И обычно для разбора строки используют регулярные выражения.

Comment: @MaksymTymofeiev, "погода в Москве". Нужно, чтобы в ссылку open weather map вставилось Москва.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$string = "погода в Москве";
$city_name = str_replace("погода в ","",$string);
echo $city_name; //Москве
```

Можно сложнее, заранее имея массив городов.